# Error while creating a bitmap xml in Android

Tags: android

I'm using android 3.0 and I try to create bitmap xml that will create a background by repeat of a pattern.

I called it pattern_4_4_repeat.xml and it is located in 'drawable':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/pattern_base"
    android:tileMode="repeat">
</bitmap>
```

It is working well and looks good when I run it. The problem is that I get an error in the Error Log that says the following:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: <bitmap> requires a valid src attribute
at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.inflate(BitmapDrawable.java:382)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:832)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:769)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:208)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:775)
at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2471)
at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:366)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:156)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:152)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor40.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:576)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:84)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:644)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:129)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:83)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:702)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:86)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:702)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:86)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:702)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:367)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:321)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:372)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1317)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1071)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener.reloadLayoutSwt(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1533)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener.access$0(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1471)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener$1.run(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4041)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3660)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
```

I don't understand what am I missing here.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved.
I've used ADT v14 when I had the problem, but after updating the ADT to v15 the error stopped showing in the Error Log.

Answer (score 0):

problem seems that @drawable/pattern_base is invalid (logcat says requires a valid src attribute ) 
ensure that drawable folder contains image with same name.

Comment: As I said, it works and looks good so I guess that all the files are OK. But just to make sure I've rechecked and the file pattern_base.png is located in drawable-mdpi (like all of my images) and the pattern_4_4_repeat.xml is located in drawable.